# How to manage unauthenticated session in android?

Tags: android, session

I am trying to implement an android app which needs the unauthentic session management.
The purpose of this app is to communicate and fetch services from publicly available website which don't need authentication or any login.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean to say. You just need to reach and end point fetch results and show it in android app. Is it ?

Comment: Partially yes, I want to fetch the services of server located remotely which is publicly available. But I am not able to figure it out, how to manage the session in android app with that server.

Comment: what do you mean by maange the session here. Can you be more specific, its too generic

Comment: Ok so here's the thing, my server side implementation has two parts, one for public and other for private users(needs login). So I want to access the method X in public implementation part which requires the session parameter to access. So how to pass that(session) parameter from android to server in order to access method X?

Answer (score 0):

Normally authentication token is sent via request headers. You can use libraries such as Retrofit or Volley to carry out communication with server. It lets you define end points, expected request and response details clearly.

Sample retrofit code here. (Just showing authentication part of it. Rest of the details you will easily get from documentation and tutorials)

```
   RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Version", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
                    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;versions=1");
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", "YOUR_TOKEN);

                }
            });
```